# VBA Exec SQL Statement

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I've been looking at this statement for ages and I'm sure its something minor. However I cannot get it to pull the data through via VBA. Strange thing is it works in SQL as a statement but as soon as I run it through VBA I get a runtime error. I could really do with a second pair of eyes.

```
stSQL = "EXEC('SELECT T1.Name FROM [dbo].[Tbl1] T1 " & _
            "INNER JOIN [dbo].[Tbl2] T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID " & _
            "WHERE T2.NAME = '" & sBizUnit & "' AND Desc = '''' ORDER BY Name')"
```

sBizUnit is a value from a combobox:

```
sBizUnit = CB_BizU.Value
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the account you are running your application under have permission to run the `EXEC` command?

Another point I've noticed is that you haven't escaped the first set of quotation marks, maybe try:

```
stSQL = "EXEC('SELECT T1.Name FROM [dbo].[Tbl1] T1 " & _
        "INNER JOIN [dbo].[Tbl2] T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID " & _
        "WHERE T2.NAME = ''" & sBizUnit & "'' AND Desc = '''' ORDER BY Name')"
```